# Turn off *print-namespace-maps* in repl

Tags: clojure

With Clojure 1.9-beta2, the reader and writer now support [a compact syntax for maps](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1910). The syntax avoids repeating the namespace in the case where all the keys are qualified keywords with the same namespace:

```
> (pr-str {:a/foo 1 :a/bar 2})
"#:a{:foo 1, :bar 2}"
```

That causes problem when sending such a serialized map to a Clojure 1.8 process: the old reader running there will fail to read it and throw a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Reader tag must be a symbol`.

Luckily, the printer only does this when the dynamic variable `*print-namespace-maps*` is truthy, and it's falsey by default, so my app continues to work in production. However, the REPL sets it to true, so when I work in the REPL and do something that ends up sending a request to a Clojure 1.8 service, it fails. **How can I disable the new syntax in the REPL also?**

I thought that maybe I could just `(set! *print-namespace-maps* false)` in my repl or add `{:user {:repl-options {:init (set! *print-namespace-maps* false)}}}` to my ~/.lein/profiles.clj, but that doesn't seem to work. I think the reason may be that the REPL uses `binding` to [create thread-local bindings](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-beta2/src/clj/clojure/main.clj#L78) for a bunch of variables including this one, and `set!` [does not work for local variable bindings](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/set!).

Comment: Take a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/XAP0ENMSUTc

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine `print-method` for maps, which should work regardless of environment.

```
(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.IPersistentMap [m, ^java.io.Writer w]
  (#'clojure.core/print-meta m w)
  (#'clojure.core/print-map m #'clojure.core/pr-on w))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `(set! *print-namespace-maps* false)` works for me. (But this is some 5 years later.)

This also works, and can sometimes be more desirable:

```clj
(binding [*print-namespace-maps* false] 
  (pr-str {:a/foo 1 :a/bar 2}))
=> "{:a/foo 1, :a/bar 2}"
```